# Multiple File Uploads fail when webform is placed in a block

Tags: webforms

I'm in Internet Explorer support hell.

I have a webform which uses [Multiple File Uploads](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_multiple_file). When the form is displayed as a regular node (e.g. www.example.com/node/4), file uploads work as expected.

When the node is shown as a block on another node, file uploads fail with the message:

> An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely 
>   exceeded the maximum file size (20 MB) that this server supports.

Needless to say, all `php.ini` configuration options are in order, (`post_max_size=128M`, `upload_max_size=20M`, etc) and the temp folder is writable.

Uploads fail specifically on Internet Explorer 8 and 9. There is no indication in the log of anything going wrong, just the error message above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had, due to custom markup added to the `webform`, nested `<form>` tags. Per the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element), this is a big no-no. What happens in the older browsers appeared to have been that the form AJAX submission tried to use the form ID of the most recent `<form>` tag, which, in my case, was empty. It [triggered this in `file.module`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_ajax_upload/7):

```
if (empty($_POST['form_build_id']) || $form_build_id != $_POST['form_build_id']) {
  // Invalid request.
  drupal_set_message(t('An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (@size) that this server supports.', 
    array('@size' => format_size(file_upload_max_size()))), 'error');
  ...
  ...
```

Removing the unneeded `<form>` tags resolved the issue.